# C3 / D3: How to add segmented benchmark overlays on top of grouped bars (vertical lines to stretch over horizontal bars)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3

I'm new to this D3/C3 thing and had a project thrown my way w/ limited time to work on it and was wondering how one would go about adding vertical thresholds on top of horizontal bars as shown in the image below, using C3 / D3 charting libs.

I've got it looking pretty spot on except for that part. Any input would be helpful (if it was meant to be helpful that is).

[image]